# PDO MySQL SELECT with multiple criteria within an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement

I am a newbie and wish to learn the following;

I wish to query MySQL with PHP (my PDO connection is $dbo);

I have a the variables;

- $form_category //an integer
- $form_subcategory //an integer
- $form_subcategory2 //text
- $fname //the file name
- $form_class // 'create' is the class in this example
- $form_location //directory where the pdf is stored

My attempt at the query is;

```
///start query ///

  $quer2 = $dbo->prepare("SELECT form_id,form_description
    FROM form_detail
    WHERE form_name < :form_name AND form_category = :form_category AND form_subcategory = :form_subcategory AND form_subcategory2 = :form_subcategory2");
        $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_id', $form_id);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_name', $fname);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_category', $catid);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_subcategory', $subcatid);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_subcategory2', $subcat2);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_class', $form_class);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_cerfa', $form_cerfa);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_description', $form_description);
    $quer2 ->execute();

   ///End new query ///
```

I wish to output the 'form_reference' and 'form_description' from the variables above as well as the form name($fname) and display it in a table with href on the filename for example; 
`echo "<td colspan=\"3\" rowspan=\"1\"  style=\"text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;\"><a href=".$dir."create/".$fname." target=\"_blank\">".$fname."</a></td></tr>";`

Comment: What difficulty are you facing. ?

Comment: I can't seem to correctly build the table from the query output if that makes sense. @Adeel

Comment: Do you want the `result` to be displayed from the DB or you just need to use these variables. ? It's a bit confusing , please be clear.

Comment: I would like the result to build me a html table with the form_id (Reference) The form description and the form name in seperate cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way  ,

```
$quer2 ->execute();
if ($sp->execute())  // Verify that result exist
{   

        $result=$quer2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $result->closeCursor();

//   Now , Access Form id and description in this way 



    echo "Form id : $result->form_id";
    echo "Form Description : $result->form_description" ; 
}
```

Another thing ,

`$quer2 ->bindParam(':form_id', $form_id);`

If It's an int modify it like this ,
 `$quer2 ->bindParam(':form_id', $form_id , PDO::PARAM_INT);`

And if string then `PDO::PARAM_STR` .

It's a good practice and gives you added security.

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens for the line containing $quer2 ->execute();

Comment: Obviously , the parameters you bound does not match the placeholders you've put into the query

Comment: You've bound these params `$quer2 ->bindParam(':form_class', $form_class);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_cerfa', $form_cerfa);
    $quer2 ->bindParam(':form_description', $form_description);` and they are not being used in your query

Comment: The form_id being output for that filename isnt correct?

Comment: Check this in your code `WHERE form_name < :form_name`  , shouldn't it be `WHERE form_name = :form_name`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object:  'if ($sp->execute())  // Verify that result exist'

Comment: you might have not set your PDO connections properly. have a look at this first.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: it works, I place my query in my IF statement, changed the > to an = and added the form_name to the select statement. @Adeel thank you SO much

Comment: I'm Glad it did :) . Please consider checking the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: I just did, was it a good question, if so please consider a vote

Comment: Novice PHP developer are often stuck in these things , but it's good that you are following the best practice , my vote for this. :) , I expect the same in return.